# neo4j - loading csv file and store line number as a property

Tags: csv, neo4j, numbers, cypher, line

I have a csv file where the line is sorted with most important entry up top.  I would like to store the line number as a property to indicate the importance.

For example:

```
Name
-----
abc
cde
xyz
```

My Cypher looks like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///test.csv'  AS line 
WITH line
```

I'd like to store line.name as a node name and a new property "rank" where the line number is stored.  Ex.   1 for abc, 2 for cde and 3 for xyz.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Not a good idea to use a line number as input. It is strongly recommended to change the csv-file by adding a column with a rank value.

As an exercise, you can solve the problem by using a temporary node:

```
MERGE (tmp:TEMPNODE) SET tmp.line = 0
WITH tmp
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data.csv'  AS line 
WITH line
MATCH (tmp:TEMPNODE) SET tmp.line = tmp.line + 1
RETURN line, tmp.line as index
```

As an alternative, try using [`apoc`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_web_apis_json_xml_csv):

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('url',{sep:";"}) YIELD lineNo, list, map
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but I'm getting the same index value returned over and again...

Answer (score 0):

*(I tried @stdob's approach with a temporary node - and variations thereof - and none worked : I kept getting the SAME index value returned over and again...)*

What worked for me was to use the Cypher function `linenumber()` (only available in the context of a LOAD CSV)  :  [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.4/functions/load-csv/)

**FULL EXAMPLE:** (assuming you have a CSV column named "Name")

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/test.csv" AS line

CREATE (n :MY_LABEL {Name: line.Name, rank: linenumber()} )

RETURN count(line)
```

The RETURN statement is optional.

Note: if on Linux, replace "file:///C:/test.csv" with "file:/test.csv"